# iOS remote push notifications are queueing up after the first when app is in background

Tags: ios, push-notification

When my app is in the background, remote push notifications seem to be getting queued up after I receive the first, then dequeued when the app returns to the foreground.

It doesn't happen all the time; sometimes I can receive more than one, but I haven't figured out what determines that yet.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"received remote push notification);
    ... process push notification
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

When the app is in the background, what I see happening is:
1. I send a push notification.
2. I see "received remote push notification" in the console.
3. I send another push notification.
4. Nothing happens.
5. I tap my app icon to bring it to the foreground.
6. Once the app returns to the foreground, I see "received remote push notification" in the console.

What I want to happen is I see the console output as soon as I receive the push notification.

Thanks in advance!